# Detail Disclosure change color on the cell with swift 3

Tags: swift3, uitableview

i have an issue with how can i change color button from blue to white color (detail disclosure on the table view cell?) i try to change the image on that button but it hide the arrow on the right side on the cell  please can help me

the following my code:

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as? MovieDownloadedTableViewCell

     if let cell = cell {
                cell.accessoryView = nil
                cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "info"))
    }
}
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show some screen shot?

Comment: this is the screen shot you can see the button which is blue color i need to change it to the white color   http://imgur.com/a/PN4dd

Comment: You want to change the color of detail disclosure button? The blue one

Comment: yes i need to change color only to white color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the `detailDisclosureButton` to white you need to set to `tintColor` of `UITableViewCell` to `white`. So set the tintColor of your cell to white, you can either set this in your interface builder or in `cellForRowAt` method like this way.

```
cell.tintColor = .white
```

Comment: @Mustafa Welcome mate :)